# Can you delete multiple branches in one command with Git?

Tags: git

I'd like to clean up my local repository, which has a ton of old branches: for example `3.2`, `3.2.1`, `3.2.2`, etc.

I was hoping for a sneaky way to remove a lot of them at once. Since they mostly follow a dot release convention, I thought maybe there was a shortcut to say:

```
git branch -D 3.2.*
```

and kill all `3.2.x` branches.

I tried that command and it, of course, didn't work.

Comment: `git branch -D $(git branch | grep 3.2*)` - this worked for me. It deletes the branches whose name starts with "3.2". `grep` - pattern matching in the output (of `git branch` in this case). `$()` - means execute and place the result. `|` - chaining.

Comment: Worth noting for those that don't know, that `-D` is a *force* delete, should use `-d` in most cases to be safer first.

Comment: This blog contains a short answer https://medium.com/@rajsek/deleting-multiple-branches-in-git-e07be9f5073c   Just ```git branch | grep "<pattern>" | xargs git branch -D``` much easier

Answer (score 522):

Not with that syntax. But you can do it like this:

```
git branch -D 3.2 3.2.1 3.2.2
```

Basically, git branch will delete multiple branch for you with a single invocation. Unfortunately it doesn't do branch name completion. Although, in bash, you can do:

```
git branch -D `git branch | grep -E '^3\.2\..*'`
```

Comment: The completion on `git branch -D/-d` works fine for me. Might want to update yours (maybe from the most recent git.git contrib directory).

Comment: Instead of `git branch | ...` you could use `$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/3.*)`. It's longer, I know, but it's guaranteed to be suitable output, while `git branch` has pretty output with things like `*` and `->` (for symrefs) which can mess you up in scripts/one-liners.

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one with this issue, but I have `grep` aliased to always include the flag `--color=always` -- `git branch -D` was throwing `error: branch 'my_branch' not found.` until I ran without the color flag.

Comment: @eebbesen Did you disable it globally? I run into the same issue when running `git branch --merged ${1-$(current_branch)} | grep -v ${1-$(current_branch)} | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: With brace expansion you could write `git branch -D 3.2{,.1,.2}` to delete all three branches https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

Comment: @eebbesen : You can do  git branch | grep --color=auto '<pattern>' | xargs git branch -d

Comment: To do the same thing using power-shell, you can run the following command:

`PS> git branch -D ( ( git branch | Select-String -Pattern '3.*') |  foreach{$_.ToString().Trim() } )`

Comment: It only deleteds local though? Because I want to delte only local copies, not remote

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Yes. `git branch -D` only deletes the local copy. If you ever need to delete the remote copy you'd need to do `git push origin --delete`

Comment: Simple tip: You can use `git pull --prune` to remove local branches that were merged on the remote

Comment: `xargs` works fine too: `git branch | grep [options] <pattern> | xargs git branch -D`

Answer (score 376):

You can use git branch --list to list the eligible branches, and use git branch -D/-d to remove the eligible branches.

One liner example:

```
git branch -d `git branch --list '3.2.*'`
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a bunch of error messages like `error: branch 'package.json' not found.`. It seems that the * is expanded too early, and it tries to delete a branch corresponding to the name of every file and directory.

Comment: This works well!
I am having problem using this as an alias with `gitconfig` though...

Comment: This answer needs to be higher in the list, super clean, works, no grep

Comment: One use case I found useful: If you use feature branch model, you can use `git branch -d ``git branch --merged master | grep -v master`` ` to delete branches that have been merged into master

Comment: Nice that this one is easy to test first by just issuing `git branch --list '3.2.*'`

Comment: I wonder if the `"Do not use output from git branch in scripts"` applies here. As technically, this is not grep'ing the output, but it's still using it recursively, and a one-liner recursive is still a 'script'

Comment: On windows `git branch -d (git branch --list '3.2.*').trim()`

Comment: On mac, I used `-D` instead of `-d` to make it work

Comment: @RannieAguilarPeralta -D delete is a force delete branch, this isn't a OS variation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/5799029

Comment: This is the best answer especially for Windows users

Comment: I modified your command and deleted all the branches except `master` and `development`. Thanks a Ton

Answer (score 213):

Well, in the worst case, you could use:

```
git branch | grep '3\.2' | xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: This is pretty much the perfect method for anyone who uses a standardized prefix notation for branch names (e.g. "fix/..." or "feature/...").

Comment: Simple and efficient! I'd recommend though running first without the `| xargs git branch -d` part to check what's actually going to be deleted.

Comment: It's recommended not to `grep` the output of `git branch`, as its meant for reading, not parsing. Could change any time. use the `for-each-ref` together with the `--format` params, as suggested in other answers, and then combine with the suggestions in this answer.

Comment: Shouldn't that say, "in the *best* case" ? ;)

Comment: @redfox05 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3678909/327074 for the equivalent of this question with `for-each-ref`

Comment: Use -d instead of -D to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 161):

```
git branch  | cut -c3- | egrep "^3.2" | xargs git branch -D
  ^                ^                ^         ^ 
  |                |                |         |--- create arguments
  |                |                |              from standard input
  |                |                |
  |                |                |---your regexp 
  |                |
  |                |--- skip asterisk 
  |--- list all 
       local
       branches
```

EDIT:

A safer version (suggested by Jakub Narębski and Jefromi), as git branch output is not meant to be used in scripting:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/3.2\* | xargs git branch -D
```

... or the xargs-free:

```
git branch -D `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/3.2\*`
```

Comment: Do not use `git branch` output for scripting.  Use `git for-each-ref`.

Comment: To delete tags with the @ symbol: `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/tags/\*@\* | xargs git tag -d`

Comment: Has a typo. Should be "/3.2/*" not "/3.2\*". Also, appears you've copy pasted other answers into your own.

Comment: No typo here. From the man page: `If one or more patterns are given, only refs are shown that match against at least one pattern, either using fnmatch(3) or literally, in the latter case matching completely or from the beginning up to a slash`

Comment: Don't know if this has changed over time, but - this works for me without the "\*" but doesn't work with it.

Comment: @jakub i'd love to know why "Do not use git branch output for scripting. Use git for-each-ref"

Comment: @danyamachine: `git branch` output is meant for end user, and can change without warning / deprecation period. For example current branch might stop be marked with asterisk '\*' and start with Unicode bullet '•'. Or amount of indent might change. Or... This is not something theoretical - the output for *detached HEAD* in `git branch` **did** change.

Comment: I feel like the `git branch` answer should be removed completely in favor of the `for-each-ref` answer.

Comment: The exargs free approached worked great for me, but with -d.

Comment: Worth noting for those that don't know, that `-D` is a *force* delete, should use `-d` in most cases to be safer first.

Answer (score 47):

Recently, I was looking for solution of same problem, finally i found one answer and it is working very well:

1. Open the terminal, or equivalent.
2. Type in git branch | grep " pattern " for a preview of the branches 
   that will be deleted.
3. Type in git branch | grep " pattern " | xargs git branch -D

This solution is awesome and if you want full explanation of each command and how it is working, its given [here](https://marceloluz.com/blog/deleting-multiple-branches-in-git).

Answer (score 38):

To delete multiple branches based on a specified pattern do the following:

Open the terminal, or equivalent and type in following commands:

```
git branch | grep "<pattern>" (preview of the branches based on pattern)

git branch | grep "<pattern>" | xargs git branch -D (replace the <pattern> with a regular expression to match your branch names)
```

Remove all `3.2.x` branches, you need to type

```
git branch | grep "3.2" | xargs git branch -D
```

That's all!

You are good to go!

Comment: This saved me so much time. I appreciate this!!

Comment: very detail and clear and correct way of deleting all branches match an expression!

Answer (score 34):

Use

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' 'refs/heads/3.2.*' |
   xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: small tip is that if you remove the latter part of the command "| xargs git branch -D" then it will just output the matching branches. So, you can preview branches that will be deleted

Comment: Also I added an alias to simplify this: `alias grefs='git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)"'` so I can then do `grefs | grep 'regexpattern' | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: Loved it. Nice and simple!

Comment: What would a pattern that excludes refs look like?

Comment: As a hack I just piped the results through `grep -v`.

Comment: I do a first pass with `git branch -d` (lowercase) which will leave all those that require `git branch -D` so that I can do a quick double-check before deleting those.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to remove all branches that are not, for example, `master`, `foo` or `bar`

```bash
git branch -D `git branch | grep -vE 'master|foo|bar'`
```

or via `for-each-ref`:

```bash
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' 'refs/heads' | grep -vE 'master|foo|bar' | xargs git branch -D
```

`grep -vE 'something'` is a matcher with inversion.

Comment: I personally like `-D` option compare to other answer. Thanks for the answer here @Adi.
Solutions works for me.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to delete multiple branches for cleanup, this will work

```
 git branch -d branch1 branch2 branch3
```

also if you want to reflect the deletion action to remote, you can use this to push them to the origin

```
 git push origin --delete branch1 branch2 branch3
```

Answer (score 20):

Here is a general solution:

```
git branch | grep "<pattern>" | xargs git branch -D
```

I would suggest running the following command line before executing the above for a preview of the branches that will be deleted.

```
git branch | grep "<pattern>"
```

In this case

```
git branch | grep "^3\.2\..*" | xargs git branch -D
```

Answer (score 17):

I put my initials and a dash (at-) as the first three characters of the branch name for this exact reason:

```
git branch -D `git branch --list 'at-*'`
```

Comment: All answers basically say this, this just happens to be the most simple.

Answer (score 16):

Keep "develop" and delete all others in local

```
    git branch | grep -v "develop" | xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: This is the best and easiest way! You can add more `grep -v` argument to exclude another branch like this: `git branch | grep -v "develop" | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D`

Answer (score 13):

If you're not limited to using the git command prompt, then you can always run `git gui` and use the Branch->Delete menu item. Select all the branches you want to delete and let it rip.

Comment: this only lets you delete local branches though

Answer (score 13):

You can use `git gui` to delete multiple branches at once.
From Command Prompt/Bash -> `git gui` -> Remote -> Delete branch ... -> select remote branches you want to remove -> Delete.

Comment: ...or use `Branch`->`Delete` in `git gui` if you want to delete local branches (as the OP asked).

Answer (score 13):

**Powershell Solution:**

If you're running windows, you can use PowerShell to remove multiple branches at once...

```
git branch -D ((git branch | Select-String -Pattern '^\s*3\.2\..*') | foreach{$_.ToString().Trim()})
//this will remove all branches starting with 3.2.

git branch -D ((git branch | Select-String -Pattern 'feature-*') | foreach{$_.ToString().Trim()})
// this will delete all branches that contains the word "feature-" as a substring.
```

You can also fine tune how the pattern matching should work using Powershell's Select-String command. Take a look at [powershell docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thanks, was about to lookup alternatives for grep in powershell when I stumbled upon your solution here :-D

Small remark though, if you reverse the order of commands, you only need to pipe once: 

`git branch --list feature-* | foreach { git branch -d $_.ToString().Trim() }`

Comment: Here is my PowerShell solution, excluding main branch:
```git branch -l | % { if ($_ -ne "* main") { git branch -d $_.Trim() } }```

Comment: And this is another one, just for record: ```git branch -d $(git branch | findstr ".*").Trim()```

Answer (score 12):

If you really need clean all of your branches, try

`git branch -d $(git branch)`

It will delete all your local merged branches except the one you're currently checking in.

It's a good way to make your local clean

Comment: This worked well enough for me. It left two branches except the one I was one which I then removed by using the same command but using a capital "-D" instead of "-d". I got a few errors about git not finding files but the branches were deleted.

Comment: This works for me. The reason you might be getting error with "-d" because it doesn't delete those branches that aren't merged. While, on the other hand, "-D" flag forcefully delete every branch despite its status

Answer (score 9):

***TL;DR***

`git branch -D $(git branch | grep '3\.2\..*')`

**Explanation**

1. `git branch` lists all the branches on your local system.
2. `grep '3\.2\..*'` uses pattern matching to find all files in the current working directory starting with `3.2.`. Using `\` to escape `.` as it's a special character for grep.
3. `git branch | grep '3\.2\..*'` will pass all the github branch names to the grep command which will then look for branch names starting with the string within the list supplied.
4. `$(git branch | grep '3\.2\..*')` Anything enclosed within `$()` will run it as a separate shell command whose result can then be passed on to a separate command. In our case, we would want the list of files found to be deleted.
5. `git branch -D $(git branch | grep '3\.2\..*')` This just does what is explained above in Point 4.

Answer (score 7):

For pure souls who use PowerShell here the small script

`git branch -d $(git branch --list '3.2.*' | %{$_.Trim() })`

Answer (score 5):

I made a small function that might be useful based off of the answer provided by @gawi (above).

```
removeBranchesWithPrefix() {
  git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/$1\* | xargs git branch -d
}
```

Add that to your `.bash_profile` and restart your terminal. Then you can call from command-line like this:

```
removeBranchesWithPrefix somePrefix
```

**Note**

I have it currently setup for a soft delete, which means it won't delete the branches unless they've already been merged.  If you like to live on the edge, change `-d` to `-D` and it will delete everything with the prefix regardless!

Answer (score 5):

`git branch -d branch1 branch2 branch3` already works, but will be faster with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021).
Before, when removing many branches and tags, the code used to do so one ref at a time.
There is another API it can use to delete multiple refs, and it makes quite a lot of performance difference when the refs are packed.

See [commit 8198907](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8198907795500a5054ad04507b9189cfa5431737) (20 Jan 2021) by [Phil Hord (`phord`)](https://github.com/phord).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f6ef8ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6ef8baba293f851b07192169f40004ce44a74c1), 05 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`8198907795`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8198907795500a5054ad04507b9189cfa5431737):use `delete_refs` when deleting tags or branches
>
> <sup>Acked-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phil Hord</sup>

> '[`git tag -d`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8198907795500a5054ad04507b9189cfa5431737/Documentation/git-tag.txt#L83)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--d))</sup> accepts one or more tag refs to delete, but each deletion is done by calling `delete_ref` on each `argv`.
> This is very slow when removing from packed refs.
> Use `delete_refs` instead so all the removals can be done inside a single transaction with a single update.
>
> Do the same for '[`git branch -d`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8198907795500a5054ad04507b9189cfa5431737/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L97)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--d))</sup>.
>
> Since `delete_refs` performs all the packed-refs delete operations inside a single transaction, if any of the deletes fail then all them will be skipped.
> In practice, none of them should fail since we verify the hash of each one before calling `delete_refs`, but some network error or odd permissions problem could have different results after this change.
>
> Also, since the file-backed deletions are not performed in the same transaction, those could succeed even when the packed-refs transaction fails.
>
> After deleting branches, remove the branch config only if the branch ref was removed and was not subsequently added back in.
>
> A manual test deleting 24,000 tags took about 30 minutes using `delete_ref`.
> It takes about 5 seconds using `delete_refs`.

Answer (score 3):

You might like this little item...  It pulls the list and asks for confirmation of each item before finally deleting all selections...

```
git branch -d `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/\* | while read -r line; do read -p "remove branch: $line (y/N)?" answer </dev/tty; case "$answer" in y|Y) echo "$line";; esac; done`
```

Use -D to force deletions (like usual).

For readability, here is that broken up line by line...

```
git branch -d `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/\* |
    while read -r line; do 
        read -p "remove branch: $line (y/N)?" answer </dev/tty;
        case "$answer" in y|Y) echo "$line";; 
        esac; 
    done`
```

here is the xargs approach...

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/\* |
while read -r line; do 
    read -p "remove branch: $line (y/N)?" answer </dev/tty;
    case "$answer" in 
        y|Y) echo "$line";; 
    esac; 
done | xargs git branch -D
```

finally, I like to have this in my .bashrc

```
alias gitselect='git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/\* | while read -r line; do read -p "select branch: $line (y/N)?" answer </dev/tty; case "$answer" in y|Y) echo "$line";; esac; done'
```

That way I can just say

```
gitSelect | xargs git branch -D.
```

Answer (score 3):

it works correctly for me:

```
git branch | xargs git branch -d

git branch | xargs git branch -D
```

delete all local branches

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to remove all branches (checked out branch will not be deleted).

```
git branch | cut -d '*' -f 1 | tr -d " \t\r" | xargs git branch -d
```

**Edit:** I am using a Mac Os

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Git GUI, which is a default add-on for Windows, then it's the simplest. You can use ctrl to choose multiple branches and delete them with one click.

Answer (score 2):

My specific case was not addressed, so I'm making a new answer...

Scenario:

- Freshly cloned repo
- No local branches created
- Many remote branches (over 100 in my case)
- I want to delete all the feature branches, `feature/myfeature` , from the remote

This is the command that I got to work:

```
git branch  -a | cut -c3- | grep 'origin\/feature' | sed 's/remotes\/origin\///' | xargs git push origin --delete
```

Thanks to @gwai for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command: `git branch -D $(printf "%s\n" $(git branch) | grep '3.2')`

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If you had all the branches to delete in a text file (branches-to-del.txt) (one branch per line), then you could do this to delete all such branches from the remote (origin): 

`xargs -a branches-to-del.txt git push --delete origin`

Answer (score 1):

### Delete local branches with PowerShell

There many answers for BASH shell. Here is a variation for PowerShell.

Search the local branch and use *Select-String* to filter the list. Join the array into a space delimited string for a list of selected branches. Concatenate the branches to the git delete branch command. Invoke the expression.

```
iex "git branch -d$((git branch | Select-String MYSEARCHExpression) -join '')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also delete all the branches with names starting with 'JIRA-'.

```
git branch -D $(git branch --list 'JIRA-*')
```

Replace 'JIRA-' with the branch prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I you're on windows, you can use powershell to do this:

```
 git branch | grep 'feature/*' |% { git branch -D $_.trim() }
```

replace `feature/*` with any pattern you like.

Comment: grep is a not recognized cmdlet for me... so I've changed for this

git branch | where{$_.Trim().StartsWith("bug")} |  %{ git branch -D $_.Trim() }

 and worked!

Answer (score 0):

I just cleaned up a large set of obsolete local/remote branches today.

Below is how I did it:

**1. list all branch names to a text file:**

git branch -a >> BranchNames.txt

**2. append the branches I want to delete to command "git branch -D -r":**

git branch -D -r origin/dirA/branch01 origin/dirB/branch02 origin/dirC/branch03 (... append whatever branch names)

**3. execute the cmd**

And this one works so much faster and reliable than "**git push origin --delete**".

This may not be the most smart way as listed in other answers, but this one is pretty straight forward, and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete many of my branches using the below shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get a list of remote branches matching the regex pattern
matching_branches=($(git ls-remote --heads | grep -E "/3.*" | awk -F'/' '{print $3}'))

# Loop through the matching branches and delete each one remotely
for branch in "${matching_branches[@]}"
do
  # Delete remotely
  git push --delete origin "$branch"
done
```

By running this I am able to delete multiple branches with some similar in the branch names. This is the output:

```
sidharth@Sidharths-Air test-repo % bash delete-branch.sh                                                  
From https://github.com/sidharthvijayakumar/test-repo.git
To https://github.com/sidharthvijayakumar/test-repo.git
 - [deleted]         3.0
To https://github.com/sidharthvijayakumar/test-repo.git
 - [deleted]         3.1
sidharth@Sidharths-Air test-repo %
```

Answer (score -1):

As in Git all the branches are nothing by references to the git repo, why don't you just delete the branches going to `.git/ref` and then if anything is left out which is not interesting in the repository will automatically be garbage collected so you don't need to bother.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Fish shell, you can leverage the [`string` functions](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string):

```
git branch -d (git branch -l "<your pattern>" | string trim)
```

This is not much different from the Powershell options in some of the other answers.

Answer (score -4):

You can remove all the branches removing all the unnecessary refs:

`rm .git/refs/heads/3.2.*`

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons: 1. it uses an implementation detail (the fact that current versions of Git store the branches as files in a certain directory). This can change in future versions rendering the answer invalid. 2. It doesn't work if the repository is located in a [separate directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt).

Comment: Also, this produces very unexpected results if you run this on a packed repository (`git gc`). Don't do that.

Answer (score -4):

`git branch -D <branchName>`