# Git command with wildcard expansion

Tags: git, wildcard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you delete multiple branches in one command with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670355/can-you-delete-multiple-branches-in-one-command-with-git)

I'm trying to clear out my old feature branches in my git repo, and I find myself typing

```
git branch -d SOME_BRANCH_NAME
```

for each branch name. Does git support any type of wildcard expansion, so I could specify something like:

```
git branch -d temp_branch_*
```

thanks

Answer (score 24):

Well, in the worst case, you could:

```
git branch | grep temp_branch | xargs git branch -d
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer than any of the ones on the question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: Just want to add that "git branch" decorates the output a bit, so this is not exactly the Right Way to do it -- it adds a `*` to the current branch in particular.  I think something like `git for-each-ref --format "%(refname)" 'refs/heads/topic/*'` is better.