# Git: How to unfetch remote branches (Github pull requests)

Tags: git, branch, pull-request

I have ran

```
git fetch upstream +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*
git fetch origin +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

And I ended up with several hundreds of branches - 4 for each pull request (head, merge, and both from origin and upstream.

How can I get rid of these branches locally, in two steps?

I have tried

```
git branch -D refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

but that says "not found".

Answer (score 9):

I usually just remove files from .git/refs and lines .git/packed-refs

Comment: Hmm that sounds like a way to break something :) But I will try too

Comment: ...and neither of them were ever heard from again.

Comment: Ha ha. Nope I am still alive :) But came here back with the same issue, this time a colleague which commits every line he changes. I need to "mute" his branches in my `gitk`.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no "out of the box" command which does what you want but it can be solved by chaining some bash commands.

The command chain to delete the local branches could look like this:

```
git branch | grep -vE '^\*' | grep 'pr/' | xargs git branch -D
```

The version for the remote branches is very similar and uses the `-r` option for the `git branch` calls.

```
git branch -r | grep -vE '^\*' | grep 'pr/' | xargs git branch -rD
```

Comment: whoa! thanks, works like a charm! you just need to add a remote name. i've just deleted 'main-rt' remote branch from 'origin' remote which I do not need in my clone of 'origin': `git br -Dr origin/main-rt`. The result was: `Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/main-rt (was 8488c870869b).`.

Answer (score 2):

Following "[Can you delete multiple branches in one command with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670560/6309)":

```
git branch -D $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/origin/pr/)
```

Comment: This seems to be quite close to what I need, but in fact, these branches are remote, and I probably need to remove the information about the remote branches, but not the branches themselves.

Comment: To be specific about why I want this: The hundreds of remote branches clutter all the ways to manage branches - GUIs, logs, command line tab completion, etc.