# Delete all local git branches resulting from git fetch

Tags: git

I see some similar questions on StackOverflow which say to run the command

```
git branch | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D
```

However this only removes branches which I have checked out at some point. My current issue is I have pulled down 54 thousand branches which I have never checked out by running `git fetch` and now I want to remove all these.

Here's what I see when I run `git checkout [TAB]`:

```
do you wish to see all X possibilities (Y lines)?
```

[image]

Comment: you're only listing local branches with `git  branch`.  You need to add the `-r` flag to list branches on the remote.  Verify the results are what you want before just plugging that in and running it!

Comment: please don't share text as screenshots. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: `git branch -r` still only shows 1 line. Not the 54k branches which have been downloaded as part of the `git fetch`

Comment: Okay. How can I remove all these indexed branches?

Comment: try `git branch -ra` and see what that gives you.  You might need to run another `git fetch`

Comment: I'll try that out. `git fetch` appears to be enumerating over 168k objects (# of branches must have grown since I ran it last) and appears to take about 5 mins to complete.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to help. Running `git branch -ra | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D` results in a number of error messages such as `error: branch 'remotes/origin/yzhao/COMM-1346-group-exceptions-only' not found.` and repeating `git checkout [TAB]` afterwards still results in the many 10s of thousands of possible results.

Comment: I think the issue you're facing is that git checkout tab autocompletes with the thousands of remote branches you could check out.  Those are distinct from branches you would delete with `-D`.  I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887385/git-how-to-unfetch-remote-branches-github-pull-requests

Comment: Try `git for-each-ref` to see what these possible branches are. There could be some special refs besides branches.

Comment: @erik258 Minor nit: `git branch -ra` is redundant. [Option `-a`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--a) includes `-r`. So it's either `git branch`  for local branches, `git branch -r` for only remote-tracking or `git branch -a` for both.

Answer (score 0):

Tab completion of `git checkout` lists not only branches, but also files. Typing `git checkout`<kbd>TAB</kbd> is not a good way to count the number of branches.

If

```
git branch -r
```

lists only one branch, then that's all the branches you have downloaded.

Comment: Yup looks like even when I do a fresh clone there's still 10s of thousands of autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: @Ozymandias Then you need to investigate what are those suggestions — are they local branches? remote-tracking branches? tags? or what?

Comment: It seems like the remote repo has 2724 branches and 48777 tags. After enabling infinite scrollback on my terminal I'm seeing `git checkout` shows each branch twice, once with an `origin/` prefix and once without the prefix, then all the tags are listed once.

Comment: Branches with an `origin/` prefix and without it are local and remote-tracking branches. Tags don't have remote-tracking tags.