# How to remove git local branch started with "local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1854"?

Tags: git, github

If I check my local git branches.

```
$ git branch
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1854-20180227
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1854-20180227#1
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1854-20180228
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1854-20180228#1
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180320
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180320#1
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180320#2
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180330
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180330#1
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1921-20180402
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1921-20180402#2
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1921-20180402#3
```

After deletion, it will look like below:

```
$ git branch
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180320
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180320#1
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180320#2
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180330
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1899-20180330#1
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1921-20180402
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1921-20180402#2
  local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1921-20180402#3
```

Would you please help me to fix the issue. Thanks in advance for your kind support.

I don't consider, is it merged or not. I have go through stackoverflow. I got some suggestions like below, but not satisfied.

1. To delete every branch except the one that you currently have checked out:

   ```
   for b in `git branch --merged | grep -v \*`; do git branch -D $b; done
   ```
2. The simpler way to delete all branches but keeping others like "develop" and "master" is the following:

   ```
   git branch | grep -v "develop" | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D
   ```

Resource Link: [Delete all local git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610327/delete-all-local-git-branches)

Comment: What about using `grep` without `-v`? Maybe something like `git branch | grep "local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1854" | xargs git branch -D` - I haven't tested this.

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks a lot. Would you please add it as answer. So that I can accept.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I haven't personally tested this, your comment suggests it was successful.

Essentially your second suggestion removed `develop` and `master` from a `git branch` output.

My thought was to reverse the filter, so that `grep` only *included* the branches with the name you were after.

```
git branch | grep "local-feat-18.3-APPLE-1854" | xargs git branch -D
```

My simple explanation is as follows:

- `git branch` outputs a list of all local existing branches.
- `| grep "mystring"` pipe the output into a grep search and only select the lines which contain "mystring".
- `| xargs git branch -D` pipe that output as a set of arguments and delete the branches.

Answer (score 1):

You can test by this git command.

```
git branch -D `git branch | grep -E '^3\.2\..*'`
```

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670479