# How to delete multiple branches in GitKraken?

Tags: branch, gitkraken

I have more than 70 local branches in GitKraken and I want to delete some of them.

Is there any way to delete multiple branches in GitKraken client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select branch
2. Press and hold Ctrl
3. Select another branch
4. Right-click on the selected branch
5. And select 'Delete n local branches'

Comment: That is the way, please, can you add the "shift" method? (1. Select branch, 2. Press and hold shift, 3. Select another branch, 4. Right-click on the selected branch, 5. And select 'Delete n local branches').

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a way to delete multiple branches at once in GK at this time.

You might want to use a terminal like `git bash` for this (`File` -> `Open Terminal` in GK if a terminal was set up in `Preferences`). [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670479/7598462) on how to delete multiple branches with one command via command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete multiple branches when they are inside a folder.For example feature/add-search

That way, you can right-click the feature fold and delete all branches which are inside the folder.