# How do we delete multiple git local branches from Github Desktop for Mac?

Tags: github, github-desktop

How do we delete multiple git local branches from Github Desktop for Mac?
I have got lot of answers regarding deleting the current branch. But, I need to delete multiple local branches at once, as I have lots of branches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670355/can-you-delete-multiple-branches-in-one-command-with-git

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

`git branch -D branch1 branch2 branch3`

Basically you have to put spaces between branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to delete all local merged braches, except your current one:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v '*' | xargs git branch -D
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete more than one branch where each branch contains similar names, like `dev-`, or `feature-`, use the following.

```
git branch | grep "dev-" | xargs git branch -D
```